# Reset the combobox iwhen a button is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I have combo box with some contents. I want it to get reset to the first item when a button is clicked.

WPF and C#.net is used.

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="categoriesComboBox" Height="40" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="{StaticResource InventoryManagementAlternatingRowBackground}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" FontSize="20" Margin="3,0" FontFamily="Malgun Gothic" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>


     private void ClearFilter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SearchFiltersControl s = new SearchFiltersControl();
        s.ResetCategoryComboBox();


    }

     public void ResetCategoryComboBox()
    {

        categoriesComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }
```

I am adding the ViewModel. Add I want to how to use this View Model to reset the ComboBox:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    namespace NextGen.Optik.UI.Presentation.ViewModels.Inventory.Contracts
    {
        public class SearchFilterCategoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            private int _categoryId;
            public int CategoryId
            {
                get => _categoryId;
                set
                {
                    if (_categoryId != value)
                    {
                        _categoryId = value;
                        RaisePropertyChangedEvent();
                    }
                }
            }

            private string _categoryName;

            public string CategoryName
            {
                get => _categoryName;
                set
                {
                    if (_categoryName != value)
                    {
                        _categoryName = value;
                        RaisePropertyChangedEvent();
                    }
                }
            }

            private ObservableCollection<SearchFilterViewModel> _filters = new ObservableCollection<SearchFilterViewModel>();

            public ObservableCollection<SearchFilterViewModel> Filters
            {
                get => _filters;
                set
                {
                    if (_filters != value)
                    {
                        _filters = value;
                        RaisePropertyChangedEvent();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected Result: When the reset button is clicked, first item has to be selected.

Actual Results: Not getting reset.

Comment: add `categoriesComboBox.SelectedValue ="-1";` instead of  `categoriesComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;` the value should be existed in the combobox's values

Comment: This is not working sorry

Comment: Why did you set "categoriesComboBox.SelectedIndex" to -1 and not to 0?

Comment: You new up a search filters control but that's just in memory. You'd need to put it in the view before anything would happen visually. Or just use the control that's already there and reset that.

Comment: `SelectedIndex = -1` clears the selection. First item is selected by `SelectedIndex = 0`.

Comment: It is not working with selectedIndex=0 also

Comment: @user3422209: Why don't you set the `SelectedCategory` property of the view model to `Categories[0]` or `Categories?.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: Yes I used SelectedCategory and it is working now                      SelectedCategory = Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryId == 1);